# Cannot setup Samba

Tags: networking, windows, setup, samba, services

I want to access files from my Raspberry on my Windows machine. I did it previously, but I resetted both my devices some time ago. I haven't made any advanced network configurations to them yet. I installed Samba on the Raspberry with `apt install samba`. Then appended to `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[shared]
path = /home/pi/shared
valid users = pi
read only = no
```

(I tried in other instances by adding or removing additional properties to the config, such as `browsable`, but the same result). Then made a Samba user with `smbpasswd -a pi`. I tried both using password and no in different instances. I used `ufw allow samba`, again, one time yes and one time no (before I didn't needed it). While installing Samba I chose both paths of that DHCP config, but the same result. Finally, `service smbd restart`. U can imagine I did all of those as root user already. The Pi doesn't show on `Network` folder, but it didn't appear before either. The way I was going was with `Add a network location`. The folder `shared` is made on Pi and made it `777` just to make sure it is not the problem, the same as on `/home/pi`. After trying to add `\\192.168.0.100\shared` or `\\192.168.0.100\pi`, the Windows tells me it can't find the location. Below is my network:

```
192.168.0.1: router
192.168.0.100: Pi
192.168.0.102: Windows
```

I'm connected to the Pi using ssh, so I'm sure the ip is right. Basically what I did before was bruteforce all known possible configurations, and none showed a good result. I checked the workgroup too and they are the same. I did multiple combinations in restarting the devices (inclusive the router). On Windows I also made combinations of `discoverable` and `file sharing` options too

What I did wrong?

Comment: Welcome. It is possible that your version of Windows will only connect via SMB2 and not SMB1 (not sure which protocol the current Samba uses). Try [this guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-access-files-network-devices-using-smbv1-windows-10) to allow SMB1.

Comment: Thx for responding. I allowed SMB1 and opposed to what happened before `RASPBERRYPI` appears under `Network` on Windows, but it says it cannot access the network path. The `Add a network location` doesn't work either. Probably is worth to notice that it worked before even if the device was not listed under `Network`. What u think @Ari ?

Comment: Not really a question belonging to Raspberry Pi? You may get better/quicker answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com